# How to know how much user has Zoomed in phonegap:android

Tags: jquery, cordova

Is there a way to know how much the user has zoomed in a phone-gap app,
Please note that i am using the default zooming provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

[Viewport Scale on iPhone, iPad.](http://menacingcloud.com/?c=viewportScale)

Comment: thanx,but i had already used iScroll to calculate that.But the link will be useful if i need to do it elsewhere.
Thanx again